# Getting MERGE Conflit in SQL. Using same table as Source and Target

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

In a CDC table if a record has `PRODUCT = 'PRIOR_VALUE'` than I need to update that records with previous entry of that records.

I have got the code working but I believe I didn't get the Merge concept.

So in one particular case I'm getting Conflict but writing the query in different way is working fine.
TBL1 and TBL2 are identical and have same data

> This code is giving me Conflict

```
MERGE INTO  TBL1 as new USING   TBL2 as old
ON (new.ID= old.ID)
WHEN MATCHED  AND new.FILE_DATE = old.END_DATE AND old.PRODUCT != 'PRIOR_VALUE' AND new.PRODUCT = 'PRIOR_VALUE' 
THEN  UPDATE SET new.PRODUCT = old.PRODUCT ;
```

> This code is running fine

```
MERGE INTO  TBL1 as new USING   TBL2 as old 
ON (new.ID= old.ID AND new.FILE_DATE = old.END_DATE AND old.PRODUCT != 'PRIOR_VALUE' AND new.PRODUCT = 'PRIOR_VALUE' ) 
WHEN MATCHED  
  THEN  UPDATE SET new.PRODUCT = old.PRODUCT ;
```

> This don't do anything however run successfully

```
MERGE INTO  TBL1 as new USING   TBL1 as old
ON (new.ID= old.ID AND new.FILE_DATE = old.END_DATE AND old.PRODUCT != 'PRIOR_VALUE' AND new.PRODUCT = 'PRIOR_VALUE' )
WHEN MATCHED  
THEN  UPDATE SET new.PRODUCT = old.PRODUCT ;
```

> Question

- Why the MERGE is behaving differently in the first two queries
- When I'm using the same table as Source and Target then the command
  is running successfully but why it doesn't update the table.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding *Why the MERGE is behaving differently in the first two queries?***

[Databricks `MERGE` documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-merge-into.html#syntax) explains what I believe is the reason for the failure of your first query (the `ON` condition is not *selective* enough):

> A MERGE operation can **fail if multiple rows of the source dataset match** and attempt to update the same rows of the target Delta table

---

**Regarding *When I'm using the same table as Source and Target then the command is running successfully but why it doesn't update the table?***

I don't have the answer for that.

Comment: Since it's a CDC so there would only be one unique pair of (ID,FILE_DATE) so the issue of data inconsistency is not there. Also I'm getting success in Type2 which also have the same dataset

Comment: exactly that's the problem - you're saying that (`ID`,`FILE_DATE`) but your condition in Q1 is on `ID` only, which (I guess) is not unique.

Comment: To restrict that i have added new.FILE_DATE = old.END_DATE inside the WHEN MATCHED  AND